# Как реализовать на backbone список

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Дан такой json файл

```
[{
    "id":"1",
    "department": "1 отдел",        
    "surname": "Фамилия",
    "name": "Имя",
    "middlename": "Отчество",
    "internalPhone": "78-95-62",
    "externalPhone": "78-95",
    "description": ""
},
{
    "id":"5",
    "department": "1 отдел",
    "post": "Заместитель начальника училища по воспитательной работе",
    "surname": "Фамилия",
    "name": "Имя",
    "middlename": "Отчество",
    "internalPhone": "78-95-62",
    "externalPhone": "78-95",
    "description": ""
},
{
    "id":"2",
    "department": "2 отдел",       
    "surname": "Фамилия",
    "name": "Имя",
    "middlename": "Отчество",
    "internalPhone": "78-95-62",
    "externalPhone": "78-95",
    "description": ""
},
{
    "id":"3",
    "department": "3 отдел",
    "surname": "Фамилия",
    "name": "Имя",
    "middlename": "Отчество",
    "internalPhone": "78-95-62",
    "externalPhone": "78-95",
    "description": ""
},
{
    "id":"4",
    "department": "3 отдел",      
    "surname": "Фамилия",
    "name": "Имя",
    "middlename": "Отчество",
    "internalPhone": "78-95-62",
    "externalPhone": "78-95",
    "description": ""
}]
```

Этот файл я сохраняю в коллекции, и вот так я её рендерю

```
this.collection.each(function(model){
    var view = this.template(model.toJSON());
    this.$el.append(view);
}, this);
```

в этот шаблон

```
<div class="department"><p>{{department}}</p></div>
    <div class="list">
        <ul>
            <li><a data-id="{{id}}" href="">{{surname}} {{name}} {{middlename}}</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

В итоге получатся список где название отдела и под ним фио сотрудника и т.д.
, а мне нужно чтобы вывелось название отдела и под ним все сотрудники этого отдела.
Подскажите как это реализовать.

Comment: Вы ведь используете `Handlebars.js` для шаблонизации?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Перед тем, как отрисовывать модели сотрудников из коллекции, вам нужно их сгруппировать по отделу. Это можно сделать, например, так:

```
var departments = this.collection.groupBy('department');

_.each(departments, function(models, name) {
    var data = {
        department: name,
        employees: _.map(models, function(model) {
            return model.toJSON();
        })
    };

    var view = this.template(data);
    this.$el.append(view);
}, this);
```

Тогда шаблон, должен будет иметь следующий вид:

```
<div class="department"><p>{{department}}</p></div>
<div class="list">
    <ul>
    {{#each employees}}
        <li><a data-id="{{id}}" href="">{{surname}} {{name}} {{middlename}}</a></li>
    {{/each}}
    </ul>
</div>
```

**Замечание**: мне кажется, что правильнее было бы несколько изменить структуру ваших коллекций/моделей, так, что бы каждый отдел был представлен отдельной моделью. Эта модель, в свою очередь, может содержать коллекцию сотрудников и дополнительные поля, характеризующие сам отдел (название, описание, ...).

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, это то что нужно, все отлично работает.